# Less strong synonym for “disastrous”

Tags: synonyms

I want to say that a particular effect may have negative consequences. I have used the word *disastrous*:

> May have disastrous consequences.

However, it is too strong. I need another word. Any suggestion?

Comment: How about *undesirable consequences*?

Comment: ...what's so wrong about "negative consequences"? I'd say this is a very good middle ground.

Answer (score 5):

For negative consequences without sounding too strong, I'd like to suggest **undesirable**, i.e. *undesirable consequences*.

From [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=undesirable%20meaning),

> undesirable
>   adjective: **undesirable**
>   1. not wanted or desirable because harmful, objectionable, or unpleasant.

Other similar words: *unpleasant*, *unwelcome*, *unwanted*

Answer (score 2):

You could call them **unfortunate** consequences.